# Как пробежать по итератору или использование std::next

Tags: c++, c++14, итераторы

Есть `std::vector<int> block`.

И есть его перебор через итераторы:

```
for(auto iter=block->begin(); iter!=block->end(); iter++){

    // Что-то делаем

    // Получаем копию текущего итератора
    auto startIter = iter;
    int length = 0;

    while (FindBlaBlaBla(*iter)){
       auto stopIter = std::next(iter, length++);
    }

    // Что-то делаем

}
```

---

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли вместо `std::next` записать `auto stopIter = iter + iter++;`?
2. Что произойдет в момент `std::next(iter, 0)`?
3. Что произойдет, если `std::next(iter, length)`, где `iter + length > block->size()`?
4. Можно ли заменить std::next() на что-то и какой в этом будет смысл?

---

P.S. Честно, не знаю, как назвать заголовок - если есть идеи получше - поправьте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0: Для `vector<int> block` вы не сможете написать `block->begin()`, только `block.begin()` - как и для `end()`.

1: `auto stopIter = iter + iter++;` Так писать вообще не стоит - смешивать в одном выражении `++` с чем-то еще с той же переменной. Но все равно у вас ничего не получится, потому что это не скомпилируется - вы же хотели спросить о `auto stopIter = iter + length++;`? Да, *для вектора* - можно.

2: В момент `next(iter, 0)` произойдет вызов `next(iter, 0)`. А после него `iter` не изменится, если вы об этом.

3: Произойдет undefined behavior.

4: Можно, например, на [`void advance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance), но сюда итератор передается по ссылке и изменяется функцией.

Answer (score 2):

С итераторами нельзя производить арифметические операции, что нельзя производить с  указательями. Если  следовать логике, то нужно себе спросить что будет означать `iterator1 + iterator2` ? Каждый хранит адрес какого то элемента, и что получим суммируя эти адреса?... Если второй итератор смещен относительно первого на x элементов, то получается так:

```
iterator + x + iterator   // нельзя
iterator + x - iterator  == x //получаем смещение difference_type
```

1. Т.е. разница итераторов, это логически нормальная операция, а сумма
   итераторов не входит в никакую логику, и итераторы имеют возможность
   выполнять первую операцию, если это итераторы произвольного доступа,
   а операции для суммы двух итераторов нет.
2. `std::next(iter, 0)` это то же самое, что и `while(0) ++iter`, т.е.   ничего не произойдет.
3. Просто итератор укажет за конец последовательности. Такой
   итератор перестанет быть нужным для использования, кроме как
   получить значение насколько было смещение от конца.
4. Смысль в том, что есть итераторы разной категории. Есть итераторы
   однонаправленные(для чтения или для записи), двунаправленные(имеют
   операцию --) и  произвольного доступа. Только  итерторы
   произвольного доступа имеют `operator +`. Чтобы получить итератор на
   n_тый элемент для, например, `std::list`, придется `n раз выполнить
   ++iter`, потому что итератор этого контейнера  является однонаправленным, и у него нет operator+. Для того, чтобы каждый раз
   не писать цикл получения итератора, существуют `std::next` и
   `std::advance`. Для итераторов произвольного доступа(например для
   `std::vector::iterator iter`) можно выполнить  `iter += n` 
   **вместо** std::next(iter, n)